# How to recertify Notes .id file if you can't get into Notes Admin

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I've got a bit of a catch-22 situation here.

My company used to use Notes, but migrated to Exchange several years ago. As such the Notes server was mothballed. I now need to get back into Notes to get some data from an old app we had.

The trouble is, all my .id files have expired. I can't recertify them, as I can't log into Notes Admin - because the .id has expired.

Is there any way round this?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: yep that should be noted in Microsofts lotus to exchange migration tasks! I set the expiration to some day after I'm should be dead and reset all the server and users id's to a known pw, its a painful process but I've seen to many people burned by this!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to open up the database from the server, if it is still around.  Otherwise, maybe turn back your system clock temporarily?

Comment: Yeah, turn back the system clock and restart Domino.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to install a new server, configure it with the same name and OU structure, create an ID that is the same as your old Notes account name, then open the database through the new server.

Answer (score 0):

This answer in not about recertifying, but rather the original problem: accessing the data in an old database.

If the db was not encrypted on the server you can:
- take db form the server
- hack the ACL with hex editor to get Manager access
(mentionned for example http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/8054e466e17a0f38852570fa005d0266?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,hex,editor,ACL
'hacking' a local ACL is procedure known by experienced Notes/Domino admins )
- you can do in Notes localy whatever you want as the manager of the databse